# Set combination

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a set S={A,C,G,T}, how many different sequences of type S of length 5 exist that contain at most one A?

I thought that the solution would be 1*3*3*3*3 because you can only have one A, and there are three other options for the rest. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean "type S" as something special or just "types"?

Comment: type S as something special

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re on the right track, but you forgot a couple of things. First count the sequences with no $A$; you missed these altogether. Then count the sequences with exactly one $A$, remembering that it can go in any of $5$ positions, not just in the first position.

Comment: So the sequences with no A's would be 3*3*3*3*3 right? And I'm not exactly sure how to count the part where the A goes in other positions. What are the steps for that?

Comment: @PresidentNick: Yes, that’s right. For the rest, there are $5$ ways to choose where to put the $A$. You then have $4$ slots to fill, and $3$ possibilities for each; can you take it from there?

Comment: Would it be 5*3*3*3*3 for that part?

Comment: @PresidentNick: It would indeed. Now just add the two possibilities together, and you’ll have the total number of legitimate sequences.

Comment: Got it! Thanks Brian :)

Comment: @PresidentNick: Excellent! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There's 5 possible places for the "A".

Answer (score -1):

the letters can repeat.
consider it and divide your states in 2 type:
count of a is 0
count of a is 1

and find the answer with axiom of sum

Comment: Number of A may be 0 too.

Comment: sorry sorry i thought it's at least one A.